# How can I insert image paperclip data into my database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm doing this heroku tutorial ( https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ios-photo-sharing-geo-location-service#add-controller-actions ), fairly simple, but it's left out a bit of information.

There is one resource total. The first migration to the Photo resource adds two columns. A lat:decimal and lng:decimal.

In the second migration, I've got...

```
class AddAttachmentImageToPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :photos do |t|
      t.attachment :image
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_attached_file :photos, :image
  end
end
```

So my schema is...

```
create_table "photos", force: true do |t|
  t.decimal  "lat",                precision: 15, scale: 10
  t.decimal  "lng",                precision: 15, scale: 10
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "image_file_name"
  t.string   "image_content_type"
  t.integer  "image_file_size"
  t.datetime "image_updated_at"
end
```

I need to add some seed data into the photos table but I don't understand how.

I've add an image, wiki.png into my app/assets/images folder.

Then from rails console, I've run...

```
Photo.create!(lat: 37.775, lng: -122.4183333, image: File.open("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/wiki.png"))
```

However, this is not working. I'm getting a

```
Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError: Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError
```

error currently. How do I get seed data into this table?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add validation of the image in your model.  Since Paperclip 4.0, at a minimum you must validate the content type of the image, or explicitly state you do not want to.  If you don't you will get `Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError`.

In your `Photo` model you need to add one of the following validators.

If you want to validate the content type then something like:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"]
```

If you want to validate only the file name then something like:

```
validates_attachment_file_name :image, :matches => [/jpe?g\z/, /gif\z/, /png\z/]
```

If you want to explictly not validate the content of the attachment then:

```
do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image
```

Or you can combine validation using `validates_attachment` if you need to check that the image is present, of a specific type, and no greater than a certain file size for example.  For more information, please see the documentation here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Answer (score 0):

Try this:--

```
Photo.create!(lat: 37.775, lng: -122.4183333, image: File.open("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/wiki.png", 'rb'))
```